# Finding Matrix invertion by multiplication

Tags: matrices

Given a  matrix $[A, B]$ where $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ invertible matrices. Is it possible to find a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}C \\D \end{bmatrix}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}C \\D \end{bmatrix}$ $[A, B]$ is invertible?

Answer (score 2):

Notably, you haven't said what the sizes of $C$ and $D$ are.

In any case, there is no matrix $M$ such that $M [A \ \ B]$ is invertible.  To see that this is the case, note that if we fix a non-zero vector $b$, then we find that
$$
x = \pmatrix{A^{-1}b\\ -B^{-1}b} \implies
\pmatrix{A & B} x = 0
$$
So, $[A\ \ B]$ has a non-trivial kernel.   We see that for any matrix $M$, $(M [A \ \ B])x = 0$, which means that $M [A \ \ B]$ will have a non-trivial kernel, which means that it will not be invertible.

For another perspective: $M [A \ \ B]$ will have rank at most $n$, but if it's square, it has to be of size $2n \times 2n$.